# jquery navigation always opens the first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, mouseenter

I have a nav element which is something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li name='first_item'>
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>item 1.1</li>
                    <li>item 1.2</li>
                </ul>
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the code that handles the the sliding down and up is:(nav is a html element which is a parent of above)

```
nav.find("li").each(
    if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
    _callback = false;
    $("<span>").text("^").appendTo($(this).children(":first"));
         //show subnav on hover
         $(this).mouseenter(function() {
             $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
     });
         //hide submenus on exit
         $(this).mouseleave(function() {
             $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
     });
     }
 });
```

what happens is when I hover over the first_item it opens the sub menus and after it's finished sliding down them, it will open item 1's sub menus as well. I'm totally lost over this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: Here's the live exampl http://kiagallery.ir/default.aspx
the red navigation bar at top is the problem, hover over gallery and you will see it

Comment: you have no `function() {` after your `each(`

Comment: Rory what exactly should I do in that function to prevent this behavior ? I'm quiet newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it seems you copyied the jquery without the function, so that isnt the problem:

nav.find("li").each(**function(){**

I think the problem is, that you travel to deep, so try this:

```
$(this).find(">ul")
```

or this:

```
$(this).children("ul")
```

From jQuery:
The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it's working now as it supposed to be and yes you're right about the .find() function.